# Netflix Recommendations?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

What should I watch on Netflix?

Please help!! So many options...

[image: netflix]

> Edit: I already watched all of the titles above (except for Space Force which hasn't come out yet)

Comment: rot13(Vf gur rqvg cneg bs gur evqqyr?)

Comment: @avazula no.. my mistake

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should watch ...

> ... [**Black Summer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Summer_(TV_series))

I'm carrying on where PiIsNot3 has left off:

> The sequence of titles are cryptic clues that clue only a few letters of the answer. Sometimes a clues is made up of several titles:
>
>  Top Boy — **B** (the "top", i.e. first letter of BOY)
>  Battle: Los Angeles — **LA** (Los Angeles, obviously)
>  Roman Empire &middot The 100 — **C** (100 in Roman numerals)
>  Heartland · Quicksand — **K** (The "heartland, i.e. middle of (quic)K(sand).)
>  Space Force — **_** (A space)
>
>  Odd Squad · Kicks · The End of the F***ing World
>      — **SU** (The odd letters of S(q)U(a)D "kick", i.e. throw out D, the end of ... (worl)D)
>  Big Mouth — **M** (the big or capital letter in M(outh).)
>  The Hollow · Mirage — **ME** (M(irag)E hollow, i.e. only its outer letters)
>  Romeo is Bleeding — **R** (Romeo is R in the NATO phonetic alphabet)
>
>  PiIsNot3 has found the overall mechanic and the first word.

Comment: Awesome! I'll go watch it now.

Answer (score 13):

Wild guess, but maybe you’d be interested in

> **Orange is the New Black**, which happens to be a Netflix Original?

Based on the tags and affirmations by the OP in the comments, I believe the show titles

> are wordplays in the style of cryptic clues. For example, *Romeo is Bleeding* might be a clue for the letter M (middle letter of ROMEO), while *Quicksand* might clue an anagram of SAND.

With that being said, I haven’t found a way to combine this mechanic into a sensible show title, but I do have a partial that may or may not be right:

> *Top Boy* = B
>  *Battle: Los Angeles* = LA
>  *Roman Empire* + *The 100* = C (Roman numeral for 100)
>  *Heartland* + *Quicksand* = K (middle letter of QUIC[K]SAND)

so that’s what I’m basing my guess off of currently.

Comment: You're on the right track! The last part of your answer is right but you still have to figure out the other parts to get the answer (also, doesn't really matter if it's Netflix Original or not)

Comment: @pirate The best I got right now is rot13(Oynpx Zveebe), based on the Mirage and Romeo titles, but I don’t know how the rest of the shows fit... Maybe a hint?

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing my guess on @PiIsNot3's answer, who already found the word

> Black

Whick, I think adds the title

> Black Panther

With the following other clues:

> Space Force + Odd squad + Kicks = **Pan** ( ?? Space force already contains the letters 'pa', and Odd should be a marker of extracting these letters somehow)
>
> End of the f*ing world + Big mouth = **th** (Because 'th' is the end of the word)
>
>  The Hollow + Mirage + Romeo = **er** ('e' is the last letter and 'r' is the first letter, so they are in the 'hollow' between the two words)

Answer (score 2):

How about

> **BLACK SUMMER**

the first part from @[pilsnot3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81707/46082)

> **BLACK**

to finish the top line

> **space** is just a space

Then maybe

> **odd** letters of **squad** = **SUD**

but then you

> **kicks** (remove) **end of .... world** (d) = **SU**

And

> Big mouth could get you **MM**

Finishing with

> **hollow**ing out mirrag**e r**omeo = **ER**

Making the 2nd line

> **SUMMER** but I’m still not fully getting cryptic clues as a concept so I don’t know how much a stretch this is

Answer (score 1):

You should watch:

> Space Force

Because:

> It hasn't been released yet, and if it's showing up as available on Netflix, you could theoretically see the show before anyone else...if it's indeed available that is. Everything else on this list will still be there when you finish (but hurry up, Space Force might not be there once Netflix realizes it and corrects the bug)!

Comment: Can you recommend something that did come out then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess :

> Cuckoo

Because :

> In the edit section we can see Cuckoo was replaced by Quicksand.
>  Or maybe it was a mistake or part of the riddle.

Comment: Sorry, it was actually my mistake :/

Comment: @pirate ok ! I guess i will need to think a little more ^^

Comment: I can just say that the titles are there for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm following my puzzle-solving mind with this answer, I hope it doesn't offend anybody.

I think you should watch:

> Either *Top Boy* or *Kicks*.

Because:

> These both have black leads.

And the reason I think you will like this is:

> Netflix is well known for *[racial profiling](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/10/netflix-artwork-personalization-backlash-racial-profiling)*. A number of the suggestions for you such as *Battle Los Angeles*, *Odd Squad* and *Romeo is Bleeding* are represented in your screenshot using black actors who are not necessarily the leads. This suggests that you normally watch things on Netflix with black leads in them.

Comment: Uhhh, not my intention. No need for knowledge of these particular titles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe the answer is:

> **Roman Empire** (Season 3 premiered on Netflix on April 5, 2019)

The reason for this is:

> This is the only series of options that started a new season a few days ago and it was produced by Netflix as a series of "original Netflix" (all other options except for  "big mouth" are not original productions of Netflix even if their broadcast was in Netflix but their production was not its way.For example "Quicksand" also airs now in Netflix but its production company is FLX).